# Как получить статус "в наличии"?

Tags: php, битрикс

Собственно сабж в заголовке. Вывожу товары через каталог, надо этот статус вывести. Не могу найти какое свойство отвечает за него. Вот [тут](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/214666/blog/14416/) нашел подробную статью про эти статусы, но название свойства не приведено :(

Comment: В настройках товара какое кол-во указано?

Comment: @NikolajSarry 0

Comment: Ну так и как вы получите "В наличии". В статье на которую вы ссылаетесь все описано.

Comment: @NikolajSarry мне нужен в принципе статус этот. В наличии или не в наличии. То есть сам признак наличия.

Comment: В настройках магазина смотрите. Там где-то есть статусы. Магазин-Настройки

Comment: @NikolajSarry я вам русским языком говорю что мне надо это свойство из кода получить, а не в админке

Comment: О том что получать надо в коде вы написали только что. штатный компонент выводит эти статусы. Опишите нормально свою задачу.

Comment: @NikolajSarry вы невнимательно читаете. Об этом уже несколько раз было сказано черным по белому. Может штатный компонент и выводит, но я не знаю какое свойство за него отвечает, а шаблон у меня уже давно не штатный.

Comment: Насколько я правильно вас понял, вам нужно проверять `$arElement['CAN_BUY']` на true или false (соответственно можно/нельзя купить). И исходя из этого выводятся статусы в зависимости от других настроек товара.

Давно не работал с битриксом. Попробуйте вот так поиграться с настройками: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXQDEL8XnTA

И найти в коде где конкретно обрабатываются эти условия и выводятся кнопки покупки/заказа. Там и будут нужные вам переменные.

Comment: @adudnik.ru про это свойство я знаю, но кажется это не то. Оно просто проверяет доступен ли товар для покупки. Для товаров которых нет в наличии оно все равно выдает `true`.